# Scrapy - SitemapSpider equivalent of start_requests method

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, sitemap

[This](https://www.iproperty.com.my/sitemap_index.xml) is the sitemap url of the website which I'm crawling. I want my spider to scrape data from pages that are starting with **/property**.

The problem is, those pages don't show me the correct response when the request is sent without headers. The request needs a user-agent header.

I come up with a solution like this. First, the urls starting with **/property** are crawled by `parse` method and this method gets an empty response. The same request is sent along with headers by the `parse` method and the correct response is going to be crawled by `parse_items` method.

The `parse_items` method is never called and shell process never starts. I don't understand why `parse_items` is not reached. Is there any way to define a method like `start_requests`, so I can override the behavior of the `parse` method for `SitemapSpider` class.

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    sitemap_urls = [
        'https://www.iproperty.com.my/sitemap_index.xml',
    ]

    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/property', 'parse'),
    ]

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=response.url,
            method='GET',
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse_items
        )


    def parse_items(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

Comment: What is `headers` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `SitemapSpider` [source code (v 1.6)](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6.0/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py) it doesn't call `parse` function as callback (like `Spider` does):

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.sitemap_urls:
        yield Request(url, self._parse_sitemap)
```

As You can see It doesn't add any specific headers.
U need to observe `SitemapSpider` source code and override some of it's methods.

I noticed another thing. I don't remember that spiders have `headers` value.
Did you mean [`DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#default-request-headers) setting?:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    sitemap_urls = [
        'https://www.iproperty.com.my/sitemap_index.xml',
    ]

    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/property', 'parse'),
    ]
    CUSTOM_SETTINGS = {
        DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS : {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
    }}
....
```

Comment: This works, but I think `DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS` should be between string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#default-request-headers) setting, which you can set on your spider itself using the [`custom_settings`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) class attribute.

If that is not flexible enough for you, go with [Georgiy’s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941374/939364) of override `SitemapSpider` or write your own spider from scratch based on it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly different approach to achieve the same? If you try using `BeautifulSoup` within scrapy then the output is what you expected. Perhaps it is the parser which is responsible to fetch the response.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy

class SitMapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sitemap'
    start_urls = ['https://www.iproperty.com.my/sitemap_index.xml']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')
        for item in soup.select('sitemap > loc'):
            yield scrapy.Request(item.text,self.parse_more_links)

    def parse_more_links(self,response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')
        for item in soup.select('url > loc'):
            if not "/property" in item.text:continue
            yield {"item": item.text}
```

Comment: This won't follow the links in the first page though. The urls starting with /property are in the second level. That's why I need to use SitemapSpider.

Comment: I got your point. I've tried to edit my post to reflect what you meant. Please check now. thanks.